# Pre-commit iterative reviews on Crucible (SVN) with patches that can be compared to baseline?

Tags: review, pre-commit, atlassian-crucible

When creating a code review via Crucible/Fisheye, I upload a patch file of local changes, generated using SVN's right-click context menu in windows (right click -> Create Patch), and successfully anchor it.

After this, some reviewers make comments and I agree to implement their changes, and so I do. I then create another patch file from my new set of local changes and upload it to the review, making sure to anchor it as well.

Now, when sliding the 'iterations' bar at the top of the review, there is no longer a way to compare changes relative to the checked-in 'baseline'. If the bar stretches from the original revision/baseline on the left to the first patch like so;

[image]

there are no changes shown in the diff view(s), almost as if the first patch uploaded has taken on the role of a new 'baseline'. The 2nd patch is always viewed in relation to the first patch, even if I stretch the iterations bar to start at the original, like so;

[image]

This looks identical to if I only compare the first patch and the second (without baseline) like so;

[image]

Why am I losing the ability to compare to baseline as soon as I upload the second patch? The diff is fine against baseline if I only upload the one patch file.